# Matlab check of checkbox is checked using OnOffSwitchState

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have an matlab gui which does not compile or run anymore since th gui functions were changed.
My previous code is this

```
isUseDriftComp = contains(get(handles.menuUseDriftCompensation, 'checked'), 'on');
```

But now

`handles.menuUseDriftCompensation.checked` is an enumeration

> ans =
> OnOffSwitchState enumeration
>
> on

Checking for a string using contains does not work.
How am I supposed to check for `on` and `off`?

This works, but is horrible to read and write

```
handles.menuUseDriftCompensation.Checked == matlab.lang.OnOffSwitchState.on
```

Comment: For me the "horrible" version which works is actually the best way to do it in the first place. It is more readable, and It will be faster to check for an equality of state (enumeration) than checking the content of a string for another string. You could even speed it up if you make your enumaration a boolean rather than a string.

Comment: The enumeration is from the matlab core language and not changable

Comment: You could wrap the check in an [anonymous function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and give it a more friendly name and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than this. MATLAB enumerations support some direct interoperability with text, so you could just write:

handles.menuUseDriftCompensation.Checked == "on"

MATLAB automatically attempts to coerce the text value into a value of the enumeration on the left hand side.